# How to properly read and write on sockets using Ada?

Tags: ada

Basically, I managed to connect several clients to a single server, but I have a problem reading from the server. I have two tasks (threads): one for reading, and one for writing.

1. The offset never gets to 0 resulting an infinite loop. How can I print `"Incoming > "` every time there is a new incoming message from server?
2. And Im not really sure about the buffer size. I tried 1..1024 but nothing get printed until server sends 1024 chars.
3. is `String'Write` a shortcut for `ada.streams.write`?

#### Writing data

```
String'Write(channel, "Hello client");
--Where channel is Gnat.Sockets.Stream_Access type
```

#### Reading data from server

```
    task body reader_task is    
      Offset : Streams.Stream_Element_Count;
      Buffer : Streams.Stream_Element_Array (1 .. 1);
   begin
     loop
      Text_IO.put_line("Incoming > "); 
      loop
          Streams.Read (Channel.All, Buffer, Offset);
      exit when offset = 0; 
          for I in Buffer'Range loop
              Text_IO.Put (Character'Val (Buffer (I)));
          end loop;
      end loop;
     end loop;
   end reader_task;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNAT sockets are created blocking, so when you call `Streams.Read` it will read from the socket until

1. your Buffer is full; or
2. there aren’t yet any more bytes to read; or
3. the socket has been closed.

In case 2, the `Read` call blocks until more data arrives. Only in case 3 will you get back an underfull buffer (in your code, `Offset` less than `Buffer’Last`).

If you have multiple clients, any of which could be sending data, you can use `GNAT.Sockets.Check_Selector` to block until one of the client sockets has data to read, and then read from that socket.

As for reading a complete input message, you can read a byte at a time until you reach a terminator (in the case of an HTTP request, that would be a double CR/LF). Of course, you need to agree with the client side what will constitute a terminator.

[The answer from @ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21581966/40851) has covered writing.

Comment: I managed to get it to work using String'Output. It works if I send from server to client but not vice versa. Do you mind take a look at hole the project on github? http://goo.gl/RvNIei  thanks you

Comment: The first problem is that `Server.readerTask` starts before `channel` is set up, so dies instantly.

Comment: You sir, made my day. The two way communication works perfectly now. Did you find any other problems?

Comment: No; I would have added a `Start` entry to `readerTask`, but the running instance isn’t visible at the point where I’d have called it, so there’d have been a lot of reorganisation needed. Glad to hear you’re over this hurdle, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the last question: `String'Write` *uses* `Ada.Streams.Write` (more accurately, since `Ada.Streams.Write` operates on an abstract type and is dispatching, it will call whatever overriding `Write` has been written for the actual stream type).  But it's not a shorthand.  `Ada.Streams.Write` takes an array of `Stream_Element` as its parameter (`Stream_Element` is probably a byte).  But `String'Write` takes a `String`, which is an array of characters, not an array of stream elements.  The implementation treats the `String` as an array of stream elements and writes each one.  In effect, it will write each character, so the result is very similar, but the constructs are not identical.  Things like `Integer'Write` will treat an integer as an array of stream elements and call `Ada.Streams.Write` on it; how the implementation does that is not defined.

`'Write` can also be used on user-defined types.  There are default rules for how this works, but you can also write your own `'Write` routine to use instead of the default.  RM 13.13.2 explains all of this.

(The first two questions seem to be about whether `Read` is blocking or non-blocking for a GNAT socket.  I don't know the answer to that.)